# JSON conversion to a specific format

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have a Java Object and trying to convert this to a specific JSON format

```
    public class Audit {
       String auditId;
       String auditData;
    }
```

and above object needs to convert to below JSON format

```
{
    "event":"auditId=100,auditData=purchase order"
}
```

how do we convert above format using Jackson parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom serializer for `Audit` class.

```
public class AuditSerializer extends StdSerializer<Audit> {

    public AuditSerializer() {
        super(Audit.class);
    }

    protected AuditSerializer(Class<Audit> auditClass) {
        super(auditClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Audit audit, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        String key = "event";
        String value = String.format("auditId=%s,auditData=%s", audit.auditId, audit.auditData);
        gen.writeStringField(key, value);
        gen.writeEndObject();   
    }
}
```

And then use this custom serializer to get JSON string for `Audit`:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new AuditSerializer(Audit.class));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);

Audit audit = new Audit();
audit.auditId = "100";
audit.auditData = "purchase Order";
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(audit));
// {"event":"auditId=100,auditData=purchase Order"}
```

---

If you annotate `Audit` class with `@JsonSerialize(using=AuditSerializer.class)`, then you do not need to explicitly register `AuditSerializer`.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=AuditSerializer.class)
public class Audit {
    ...
```

And you use `ObjectMapper` directly.

```
Audit audit = new Audit();
audit.auditId = "100";
audit.auditData = "purchase Order";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(audit));
// {"event":"auditId=100,auditData=purchase Order"}
```